# Allow users to create their own categories and add items to it

Tags: database, categories, user-defined

I want to allow any user to create a category using a text field. I want to let them create any number of categories they want, with any name they want. The problem is I have no idea how to set up the tables to accomplish this. I know the PHP to check to see if it exists for the user and update or add it, how do I store it?

Here's how I thought about doing it.

Table: Categories
Columns: category, id, userid

User adds a new category
Create a new record that has a category, id, and userid.

User deletes a category
Find the related row and remove it

What I'm concerned about is having a large number of users creating a large number of categories and the table having an excessive number of rows. Is that a valid concern? Will it cause performance issues if the number of rows gets into the millions?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You just need a powerful enough database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this boils down to is a one too many relationship, at the time I posted this I just didn't understand what that meant.